# Extracting particular type of strings from a txt file

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7, extract

I have a sql file which has two column fields called 'email' and 'pass' .
A sample part is as follows

```
'vloz54yC7q9p85i2Uwdi', 'zurunet', 'zurunet@hotmail.com', '', '', '', '', '',     'http://www.bnadm.com', '1a36c4e04a065e1840132b64a1b0a2a8', 9, '1186148119', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', 0);
INSERT INTO `nuked_users` VALUES ('avtGdl4zt9woGjXevy3j', '1aflam',    'zaiker_8@hotmail.com', 'zaiker_8@hotmail.com', '', '', '', '', '',    '13530b1a10329459789c8972909dddb4', 1, '1186451181', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', 0);
```

what i am trying to do is extract only the user emails and passwords .

For this, How could I extract the all of strings with *@hotmail.com*,at the end. 
If the txt file's name is foo.txt,

```
fo = open("foo.txt" , 'r')
listme = fo.readlines()
```

listme will be a list of characters in that file and i need to filter out only those strings with @hotmail.com at the end.

Comment: I suggest removing the hashed password from your post, as it would be possible for someone to reverse engineer your password from it.  Given that you also show your email address, the avenues for attack by someone malicious are fairly wide open.

Comment: I have knowingly kept a fake md5 . It is not as same as the one in my .sql file .

Comment: why my topic is kept on hold ? Was it just for seccurity reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
with open("foo.txt" , 'r') as foo:
    listme = foo.read()

string =  listme.strip().split(',')
new_string = ''


for words in string:
    if words not in new_string:
        if '@hotmail.com' in words:
            new_string+=words


print new_string
```

this will open the file (using a with statement), then read it, it then splits up the large string at each comma, then it uses a for loop to iterate through each string and lastly a condition that will check if its already been used if not another condition picks out the strings with `@hotmail.com` in them!

the output of this is:

```
'zurunet@hotmail.com' 'zaiker_8@hotmail.com'
```

Comment: can i do something to avoid repeating of emails ? pretty sure  set() wont help me.

Comment: There you go i edited it ! it should work